# django-seo - nothing is displayed

Tags: django

I have one app in my django project.

I created seo.py file and add:

from rollyourown import seo

```
class MyMetadata(seo.Metadata):
    title = seo.Tag(head=True, max_length=68)
    description = seo.MetaTag(max_length=155)
    keywords = seo.KeywordTag()

    class HelpText:
        title  = "This will appear in the window/tab name, as well as in search results."
        keywords = "A comma separated list of words or phrases that describe the content"
        description = "This will appear in the description"

    class Meta:
        seo_views = ('app_name', )
```

in my base.html in `head` I added:

```
{% load seo %}
{% get_metadata %}
```

but nothing is displayed. What is wrong? (Of course, I added data in the admin panel - My metadatas (View))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading a template tag library will not work if you haven't put that application in your INSTALLED_APPS variable in settings.py. Have you put rollyourown.seo in there?

The paths you need to set up should be in the format '/pagename/'. For your homepage you just need '/'.

Comment: Yes, I added this, but this work if I add my metadate in -> My metadatas (Path) with path "/" in admin panel. How to set metadata in all site?

Comment: Do I need to set for each path separately?

Comment: Yes, typically for good SEO practices you would want different meta data on each page.

Answer (score 0):

@ringfirebug, probably you already solved your issue, but I will answer.
You don't need to set Path for each page. Use Model, Model Instance or a view. From your configuration I see that you have still a default view in seo_views. It should look like this to start working:

```
class Meta:
    seo_views = ('your_app_name.view_name',)
    seo_models = ('your_model_1', 'your_model_2',)
```

So, when creating a new Metadata entry in Models or Views you will be able to see these models and / or views in the select box.

Next, in your template, if it still doesn't work, you have to get seo data exactly for this object,
this worked for me.

```
{% load seo %}
{% get_metadata for obj as metadata %}
{% metadata %}
```

Here 'obj' is the object, for example you product that you path to the template through your view by RequestContext.

Let me know if you managed to solve it.

By the way, if you already have managed to use external data in your metatags, like "Best {{ product.name }} of the year", let me know how.